# Java type cannot be resolved

Tags: java

I have a statement

```
String pass = com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getUserPassword(renderRequest);
```

that causes the following error in eclipse IDE:

> The type javax.servlet.http.HttpSession cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Why is this error occuring? I have added an import statement for the type but yet the error remains. How can I remove this error?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't referenced the right libraries. Add a reference to servlet.jar.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the definition of that class (usually contained in a servlet.jar file) into the build path of your project (right-click on the project, select "Properties" and then "Build Path").

Answer (score 2):

Check your project setup. If I recall correctly, this has to do with com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getUserPassword(renderRequest) using javax.servlet.http.HttpSession under the hood, but eclipse isn't able to find that class. Try adding the servlet api jar to the project class path

Answer (score 2):

Download Apache-Tomcat. Browse to the lib folder. Now open eclipse and go to build-path-> configure build path-> add external libraries.

Answer (score 2):

In order to remove this error You need to add the Servlet API to your classpath. In Tomcat 6.0, this is in a JAR called servlet-api.jar in Tomcat's lib folder. You can either add a reference to that JAR to the project's classpath, or put a copy of the JAR in your Eclipse project and add it to the classpath from there.

If you want to leave the JAR in Tomcat's lib folder:

Right-click the project, click Properties.
Choose Java Build Path.
Click Add External JARs...
Browse to find servlet-api.jar and select it.
Click OK to update the build path.

if you copy the JAR into your project:

Right-click the project, click Properties.
Choose Java Build Path.
Click Add JARs...
Find servlet-api.jar in your project and select it.
Click OK to update the build path.